# PDFsharp open XGraphicsPath

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I'm drawing a path on a PDF page using PDFsharp. I add all points to an XGraphicsPath path and then draw the path on an XGraphics. However, the XGraphicsPath always closes my path (so it always connects the end point to the begin point). Is it possible to not connect the end points so that I have an "open" path? I coundn't find this functionality in the documentation of PDFsharp.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but it seems you have to do nothing special to get an open path:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/Graphics-sample.ashx#Stroke_an_open_path_12

You do not show any code so no-one else can try your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked this 3 years ago but I have been using GDI+ and PDFSharp some lately and I had this exact problem so maybe I can help someone.

I had a loop drawing a bunch of polylines in GDI+. I decided to try to optimize this by changing a loop of DrawLines calls every time my control was being drawn into a one-time loop of `GraphicsPath.AddLines(PointF[])` calls.

As soon as I made this change, calling DrawPath would draw all my lines (which used to be separated) as one long continuous path from start to end.

I added a `GraphicsPath.StartFigure()` call before the addlines and it broke apart all my polylines and drew them the way I intended.

```
GraphicsPath myShapes;
for (int i = 0; i < PLineCount; i++)
{
    PointF[] points = new PointF[PLineCount];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < PLinePointCount; ii++)
    {       
        points[ii] = new PointF(X, Y);
    }
    myShapes.StartFigure();  // This is what I added to break the line segments apart.
    myShapes.AddLines(points);
}
```

This code won't run as written, you have to add code to provide the numbers of points in the polylines, and the X,Y coordinates of each point. Whether you have predefined shapes or you want to randomly generate them is up to you.

I have verified XGraphics has StartFigure just like GDI+ so I think it likely this will solve your issue.

Here's images of the undesirable version, and the one that was fixed by adding StartFigure before each shape.

GraphicsPath screenshots :
[image: GraphicsPath screenshots]